# 'Receiver has no segue with identifier' when identifier exists

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, interface-builder, uistoryboardsegue

For an iOS app, I have a story board and multiple controllers, and a segue going from controller **GameClass** to controller **SettingsClass**. The segue, in view Controller **GameClass** has an identifier called **GameToSettings**:

[image]

However, when I want to call the segue from my **GameClass**:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"GameToSettings" sender: self];
```

I get the error message

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<GameClass: 0xcf0c550>) has no segue with identifier 'GameToSettings''
```

I tried many tips I found in other articles (like renaming the storyboard, cleaning the project, changing simulator format, giving another name to the segue, ), but the issue keeps coming.

I've uploaded a version of my code here: http://www.petits-suisses.ch/Issue.zip.
Any suggestion of what I could continue trying ?
Thanks.

Comment: Upload your project somewhere and post a link here, I'll have a look at it.

Comment: is the settings controller embedded in a navigation controller?

Comment: The flow is the following: Navigation controller -> Menu Controller --(presentViewController)-> Game Controller --(performSegueWithIdentifier)-> Settings Controller.

Comment: Duci9y: I've uploaded the code onto http://www.petits-suisses.ch/Issue.zip. Click on the red dot, then on the blue one. The error will then appear. Thanks for your proposal !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should not instantiate your view controller this way:

```
GameClass *myNewVC = [[GameClass alloc] init];
```

Instead, use

```
 [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"storyboard name" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vc identifier">]
```

Edit:
Take a look at https://github.com/mac-cain13/R.swift

It will allow you to instantiate it easily with autocompletion, type safe method: `R.storyboard.main.myViewController`